# Switching power to a device from a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, dc, boost, conversion

### Situation:

I need to turn off power to a 5V lcd screen hooked to a 3.3V microcontroller when it is off, otherwise the lcd screen pulls power all of the time.

The goal here is for the LCD screen to only be on when a GPIO pin from the microcontroller supplies voltage, so that the LCD screen can only be on when the microcontroller tells it to.

### Problem: (all solutions I've tried)

-Using a low side n-channel mofset transistor (my preferred way of switching) isn't possible as some of the gpio pins of the micro controller are being used as drains to ground.

-Using a high side p-channel mofset transistor is not preferred because it would require a constant voltage to keep the lcd screen off.

-Using a high side n-channel mofset transistor, even though it would do the job perfectly, isn't possible (so far) because it would require 7V minimum voltage to the gate to switch the 5V drain-source current when the most this micro controller can put out is 5V, and DC step ups are too large and expensive to do the job and I dont know how to make a boost circuit myself.

-Simply attatching didoes to the gpios so that they can't drain to ground won't work, as they drop the voltage too low for the lcd screen to detect.

### Question:

Are there any other ways I can switch a 5V power supply with 3.3V GPIOs on the high side in a simple and compact manner? 
If not, how can I boost the 5V to 7V to make the high side NPN possible without using a hefty circuit or premade device?

Comment: Have you looked at latching relays? Or can you not send an off signal when the micro turns off?

Comment: You could use a relay or mosfet.But with mosfet you should use a charge pump to open the n channel mosfet.

Comment: @Samuel I'm afraid most relays, latching included are definitely not compact. I'm aiming for something that won't take up nearly that much space for this application.

Comment: @StefanMerfu I have tried using mofset transistors. Can you please elaborate on the charge pump?

Comment: Why not connect to the enable input of whatever regulator it's using?

Comment: Can you please explain what's being connected to what, and what you mean by enable input, and regulator? I didn't mention either of these things in my question so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you explain the problem with a low-side NPN?

Comment: @Samuel yes, the purpose of using a low side NPN would be to cut off the circuit's access to ground, which would stop the flow of electricity to the circuit, the problem here is that gpio pins on a microcontroller are being used to control the device, and when the main ground is cut, due to the nature of gpio's, they are being used as ground.

Comment: Errm....   NPN MOSFET?  Wouldn't that be n-Channel MOSFET?

Comment: You can get relays the size of quarters or smaller. A reed relay would be the size of a glass fuse or smaller.

Comment: And is the 5V not available constantly?

Comment: @Passerby Hey, could you make a response on that reed relay? I think it may be my solution.

Comment: @Skyler Seriously? Did you even look at relays before claiming they are too large before?

Comment: @Samuel I have many mofsets available to me and would prefer to use switches. I have little experience with relays and the ones that I've worked with in the past have either been too large or the magnetism caused by the coil too harmful to nearby hardware. Thank you for being so constructive and helpful in your comments, leading to more fruitful discussion, in this place where people come to learn about things like reed relays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a PNP/P-Channel high side switch setup is best, with very low if any current draw while disabled (leakage current only), another solution is a physically small relay.

Reed Relays are one type. Regular electromechanical relays can also be ***commonly*** found in tiny packages.

[image]
[image]

As the load is minimal, either will do. 0 draw when disabled, the reed relay from radioshack (Sku: 275-0232) has a 20 mA coil current at 5V when on. This can be reduced by PWM or other tricks, as the coil will hold the contacts down to a voltage of 0.5V. Lower voltage, lower current draw.

Comment: I ended up using reed relays for this setup, specifically this reed relay : http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/240/HE3600%20revised-275229.pdf. It works perfectly, and can switch the larger device's power with the smaller gpio, and requires no power when off.

Comment: 10mA current draw, nice.

Answer (score 5):

> Using a high side p-channel mofset transistor is not preferred because it would require a constant voltage to keep the lcd screen off.

This statement doesn't make sense. A P channel MOSFET and pull-up resistor is a very standard way of switching a power rail. Switching 5V from a 3.3V GPIO pin takes a couple extra components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft9E7e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A logic high on the GPIO pin will turn your switched rail on. C1 is optional. It is there to limit the inrush current by slowing down the \$V_{GS}\$ transition. You'll probably want it there if there is significant capacitance on the switched net. That verification is up to you.

Comment: To be fair, this consumes \$50\mu A\$ when it's turned off!

Comment: @Daniel Which is exactly why I couldn't use the P channel switch, because this device is on battery power, which is what leads the drive for this LCD screen to be turned off! I suppose I should've mentioned that, that is my fault.

Comment: That was somewhat tong-in-cheek.. you should reframe your question to give power requirements.

Comment: @Daniel how does this consume any current when off? When the GPIO is low, Q1 is off, R1 pulls the gate of Q2 to source, and Q2 turns off. The only current would be leakage trough the (switched off) Q1 and Q2.

Comment: +5 -> 100k -> 1k -> Q1 -> Ground \$\approx 50\mu A\$

Comment: @Daniel No it doesn't. P channel MOSFETs do not turn on until \$V_{GS}\$ goes negative.

Comment: @Skyler I use almost this exact circuit in a battery powered device.

Comment: @Daniel When "+5 -> 100k -> 1k -> Q1 -> Ground ≈50μA" is true, the P-FET is **on**, not off.

Comment: @jms, OP, yeah you're right about that. Sorry!